# How to use connection pool with Spring Boot + Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I am learning Spring Boot and I have created a simple application.

**I use the following maven dependencies:**

- spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.1.RELEASE
- mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.2

I would like to use connection pool to increase the speed of my application but I am not sure how to configure Spring Boot and MyBatis for this use case.

Before that I used Java EE + application server and I configured mybatis via mybatis.xml file to use JNDI data source. The connection pool was provided by application server.

But now, I am a little bit confused where to put database connection parameters because there are two possible candidates: `application.properties` and `mybatis.xml`.

**What is the connection between these two config files in this environment?**

I know Spring Boot application runs on Tomcat web container so I am not able to create JNDI data source and connection pool in it.

What is the proper way to specify database connection + connection pool when I use Spring Boot with Mybatis?

Currently I added the connection parameters to mybatis.xml and application.xml file as well:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=...
```

**mybatis.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <environments default="jdbc">
        <environment id="jdbc">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
            <datasource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="..." />
                <property name="url" value="..." />
                <property name="username" value="..." />
                <property name="password" value="..." />
        </environment>
    <environments>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What does the example of the documentation do? https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml, http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

Comment: That is an old example. I use the latest Spring Boot where there are new annotations and classes. For ex. I do not need to use constructor injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `mybatis-spring-boot-started` you don't need to use `mybatis.xml` to specify datasource parameters. It is not used for database accesses initiated from spring.

In order to add connection pooling you need to add a dependency to any of the connection pool [supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) by spring-boot. The easiest way it do add a dependency to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc`. If you have it the connections are already pooled.